# Post method in Link using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to do post method in Link,
below is the code and when i click on start link, nothing is triggering.
what do i have to change in below code?

html,

```
<form action="/" method="post"><a href="/" class="fromTop brk-btn-start" type="submit">Start</a></form>
```

node js code,

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/BGV_index.html');
});
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
    seealert();

    //res.send(name + ' Submitted Successfully!');
});
var server = app.listen(5000, function () {
    console.log('Node server is running..');
});
function seealert()
{
    alert("clicked");
}
```

Comment: I don't believe alert has any behavior in Node.js. You might also set your form `action="http://localhost:5000/"`

Comment: i tried-<form action="http://localhost:5000/" method="post"><a href="/" class="fromTop brk-btn-start" type="submit">Start</a> and removed alert. but nothing is happening when i click on start link

Comment: In function seealert, use console.log instead of alert. Then, if that endpoint is getting hit, you will see it in the console. And your anchor tag should be a button instead of an anchor I believe.

Comment: i tried using console.log but nothing is happening. btw i should use anchor tag only here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem 1

Forms are submitted with submit buttons, not links.

```
<form action="/" method="post">
    <button class="fromTop brk-btn-start">Start</button>
</form>
```

## Problem 2

> ```
> function seealert()
> {
>     alert("clicked");
> }
> ```

Node.js **doesn't have** an `alert()` method. It's a browser-specific API.

You need to respond to the HTTP request by *sending an HTTP response*.

e.g.

```
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/some_document.html');
```

That response could be an HTML document (stored in the file `some_document.html` with the above example) which includes:

```
<script>
    alert("clicked");
</script>
```